# Best UI for horoscope/zodiac Android app

Tags: mobile, navigation, android, mobile-application

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNGLwO.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I want to make horoscope Android applicaiton, and I'm not sure which navigation I should use.

I'm thinking about these two options:

- ListView/GridView with two or three columns with just only icon and horoscope sign name. So user need to click on that horoscope sign and full horoscope text will be show in new activity (new window).
- ListView/GridView with one column with icon, horoscope sign name, and full horoscope text. So with this option user dont need to open new activity.

In the first option user would be able to swipe left or right to open full horoscope text for  next or previous horoscope sign.

Also, I am thinking that I should give user possibility to drag their horoscope/zodiac sign to top of both lists.

The application is intended for the average user who likes to read horoscope on a daily basis. Length of full horoscope text for daily horoscope is about 4-5 sentences, while weekly or yearly horoscope have few more sentences. Application should also be optimized for the tablet.

Comment: A wireframe would help visualize the options you are considering. Try using this site's built in Balsamiq editor.

Comment: I think expandable list will be better in ur case.

Comment: I have been thinking about expandable list, but what about tablet layout? I guess multi pane layout for tablet would be better solution, because otherwise expandable list would look too stretched and too empty.

Comment: Just added wireframe pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could depend on what the application is for, but I think the one with 12 icons could be better, since a user often only cares about his or her own horoscope. In the first option, you could save the horoscope user chose and jump directly to that horoscope next time he or she opens the application. The second option is also harder to use if the text is scrollable. If you touch the text field, you scroll the text, while if you touch the cells below, you scroll the table. That's not a conflict, but could still be frustrating. In addition, the first option could have larger areas for beautiful horoscope icons, and a beautiful background behind them. The second option, on the other hand, could be kinda boring.

One advantage the second option has over the first one, though, is that if the user actually cares about multiple horoscopes and the text field is short, the second option would be more efficient since the user could leave several cells open and read all of them without switching view.

Comment: The application is intended for the average user who likes to read horoscope on a daily basis. Length of full horoscope text for daily horoscope is about 4-5 sentences, while weekly or yearly horoscope have few more sentences. Application should also be optimized for the tablet. Which layout you think I should use?

Comment: If you are gonna add daily, weekly, and yearly options, then I think the first option is better since you can add those buttons in the detail view, while for the second option, there will be too many buttons cluttered in a single view.

Comment: Daily, weekly and yearly options I will add through Android Tab bar. What do you consider with first option, layout with expandable listView?

Comment: the first option is the one with 4 * 3 gird. I think the the first option is still better since tab bar still adds three buttons, and a new level of hierarchy to a view already full of buttons. 2. In the second option, there would be a lot of horoscopes the user has no interested in on the view.